Is selective cell history in version 14.1 possible?
I've recently upgraded to version 14.1 and one feature that caught my attention is the enhanced linking of computation flows in notebooks. However, I am concerned about the impact of $HistoryLength on this feature. As many others here do, I typically keep my $HistoryLength set to a small number (~3) to reduce notebook bloat. However, with 14.1, a new and convenient use for $HistoryLength exists, linking the input of one cell to the output of another cell. But this link only lasts as long as the linked cell is stored in Out
Is there a way to selectively keep only certain cells in the history recorded by $HistoryLength? Ideally, I would like to preserve specific cells for further linking while excluding others to manage memory and performance better.
Also, where is the Documentation for this new feature? this is the best I found: https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2024/07/yet-more-new-ideas-and-new-functions-launching-version-14-1-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/

But the whole idea of this "smart percent" is that you can leave it in, and you will be able to recreate the expression by either reconstructing it from the output cell or reevaluating the input cell, even if you terminate the session or if you exceed $HistoryLength ...

Anyhow, I guess you could set $HistoryLength = ∞, then periodically look at DownValues[Out] and UnSet those you do not want to keep ... ?

"I typically keep my $HistoryLength set to a small number (~3) to reduce notebook bloat" - I don't think it works like that, $HistoryLength will not have any effect on notebook size. It can save memory in the kernel in cases where there was large output that was not assigned to any variable, but it doesn't affect what the front end writes to the notebook as far as I know.
